# When you go fast

Tags: riddle, rhyme

When you go, I may show.
You fear me.
I'll blast if you're fast.
You'll hear me.
You'll get a balloon and very soon,
someone will come and clear me.

Who am I?

Hint:

> It may be easy to get stuck on the word "balloon" because it stands out a bit. It is more important to first figure out what "go" can mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> a car in a motor vehicle collision?

*When you go, I may show.*

> When a person goes and drives a car, they may get into a motor collision with another car.

*You fear me.*

> Obviously, a motor vehicle collision is a very scary situation no one wants to be in.

*I'll blast if you're fast*

> If the car is going too fast, then a motor vehicle collision could result in a blast.

*You'll hear me.*

> This could refer to the loud noise a collision creates.

*You'll get a balloon*

> Balloon might be referring to the airbag in a car which inflates in a collision

*and very soon, someone will come and clear me.*

> Emergency teams or a tow truck will arrive and clear the collision scene.

Comment: Yep, or more precisely the event itself and not an object involved in it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> Diarrh##

> When you go, I may show.

> ...

> You fear me.

> at least I do, it kills lots of people each year.

> I'll blast if you're fast.

> if you’re far away from the washroom, and go into a rush, you might get a blast

> You'll hear me.

> yes I do

> You'll get a balloon and very soon,

> ya, the balloon will explode, though

> someone will come and clear me.

> don’t worry, after the blast, people will clean it up

(**writer’s note**: this is partly answer, partly for fun)

Comment: Yup, this must be the right answer 

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer, but could it be

> some type of alcoholic beverage?

*When you go, I may show.*

> Alcohol is a common item in stores and restaurants.

*You fear me.*

> People addicted to alcohol might fear it or the effect it has on them

*I'll blast if you're fast.*

> You're supposed to slowly drink some alcoholic beverages, especially strong ones.

*You'll hear me.*

> Not totally sure about this one...maybe it has to do with the sound of pouring another drink?

*You'll get a balloon...*

> A [*balloon*](https://www.google.com/search?q=balloon+drinking+glasses&tbm=isch) can also mean "a large rounded drinking glass, used for brandy and other drinks."

*...and very soon, someone will come and clear me.*

> This could refer to a bartender coming to pick up your glass when you've finished.